# How do I see the size of all .XML files in subdirectories on Linux

Tags: linux

This a stupendously simple question.

How do I see the total bytes consumed by XML files in a subtree?

I've tried `ls -R *.xml` but it says `No such file or directory`

(I'm a Windows Engineer and C# Programmer of 16 years, and despite reading Linux books it does not stay in my head).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `find` to search for files. `ls` shows everything starting at the given point, so if there is no xml file in the current directory, it cannot show anything. Use `du` to report the file size.

```
find . -name '*.xml' -exec du -b {} +
```

Comment: Wow. Just, wow. Can I get a total?

Comment: @LukePuplett: Sure. Just append `| perl -lne '$s+=$_ }{ print $s'` to the line.

Comment: Just to confirm `find . -name '*.xml' -exec du -b {} + | perl -lne '$s+=$_ }{ print $s'` is the Linux equivalent of `dir *.xml /s` right?

Comment: @LukePuplett: I do not know. `dir` might report much more than the pipeline. Have you tried it?

Comment: That's fair enough. In DOS its just that `dir *.xml /s` will simply list all XML files and summarise the count and totals at the bottom. I guess I'm surprised that Linux techs have to type and know so much in order to get a simple total.

Comment: @LukePuplett: That's what you pay for flexibility. You can easily add options to the pipeline to only list files changed in the last week, containing given strings, or make subtotals based on the owner of the file. Can `dir` do that, too? (Moreover, you can always save the perl oneliner into `~/bin/sum`.)

Comment: Some of that, yes. Else PowerShell can do anything really since its based on real .NET types. But again, we're back to having to eat an 800=page book to get a 2 second job done.